# Move zsh settings from Arch live to Arch regular

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, virtualbox

I just installed Arch as a guest (Virtual Box), and I really liked the way that the shell behaved on the live version of Arch.

What would the steps be in order to copy those settings (from live) onto my fresh Arch install, if possible?

Comment: When down-voting please tell me why (what I can do to improve question)

Comment: I don't think this is bad question at all. In fact I searched this question myself. Some people just downvote without a reason I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need the `grml-zsh-config` package like:

```
pacman -S grml-zsh-config
```

...and maybe to set your default shell to `zsh` like:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh [username]
```

You might also want to check what else you can get like:

```
pacman -Ss zsh
```

Comment: I didn't need to change the shell to zsh by default, but that was an extra.

Comment: @NoTime -- please take the time to review the last edit.

Comment: I actually used `pacman -Ss zsh` to find what package `zsh` was in (thought it was zshell), prior to downloading. I didn't know that `grml-zsh-config` was what made `zsh` so spiffy. I also added some of the autocompletes, as well as the "fish-like" components. I already upvoted you once :) the answer helped.